How to test a Token Post with Xunit
I did a request PostAsync to get a token with my credentials. I cannot find a way to test it with Xunit.
Here it is what I have:
  public async Task<string> GetToken(string url, string clientId, string clientSecret)
  {
      string accessToken = null;
      // Combine the credentials into a single string
      string credentials = $"{clientId}:{clientSecret}";

      // Encode the credentials in Base64
      string encodedCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials));

      // Create an HTTP client
      using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
      {
          // Set the Authorization header with the encoded credentials
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedCredentials);

          // The data to send in the request body
          var requestData = new StringContent("grant_type=client_credentials", Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

          // Make the POST request
          HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, requestData);

          // Read the response
          string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

//code to extract the access token from content
          accessToken = ExtractAccessToken(responseContent);
      }
      return accessToken;
  }

the test I did:
public ApiServiceTests()
{
    _httpClientMock = new Mock<HttpClient>();
    _apiService = new ApiService(_httpClientMock.Object);
}


[Fact]
public async Task GetToken_ShouldReturnToken()
{
    var clientId = "testClientId";
    var clientSecret = "testClientSecret";
    var expectedResponseContent = "{\"access_token\":\"token_value\"}";

    var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();


    mockHttpMessageHandler.Protected()
        .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
            "SendAsync",
            ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
                req.Method == HttpMethod.Post &&
                req.Headers.Authorization.Scheme == "Basic" &&
                req.Headers.Authorization.Parameter == Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"{clientId}:{clientSecret}")) &&
                req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result == "grant_type=client_credentials"),
            ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        )
        .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            Content = new StringContent(expectedResponseContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
        });

    var httpClient = new HttpClient(mockHttpMessageHandler.Object);
    var apiService = new ApiService(httpClient);
    var url = "http://example.com/token";
    // Act
    string accessToken = await apiService.GetToken(url, clientId, clientSecret);

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull(accessToken);
    Assert.Equal("token_value", accessToken);
}

When I run await client.PostAsync(url, requestData); I get a Not Authorised error. I lowered the antivirus, when I use the url: https://api.example.com/endpoint I get a response without the access token. How can I do to get a Mock response with the access token?

Please read HttpClient Guidelines for ,NET. You're not supposed to new one up, each tme you need it.
